# Automatic date stamp backup bat file changes stamp by itself after second loop

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, backup, datestamp

So I've been trying to make a automatic backup and date stamp bat program for a folder and its contents. The first time it loops it does exactly what i want it to. But the second time the loop runs, it changes the folder by removing the first 3 numbers and the 0 in 2014.
It looks like this.

First loop C:\users\username\desktop\05.26.2014\17.11\contents(This is right)

Second loop C:\user\username\desktop\6.2.14\17\contents

Third loop C:\users\username\desktop\2.1\no time folder\contents

There is a time sub folder in the date folder it is also affected by this until it does not generate anymore.
Can anyone tell what is causing this, here is what i have in the bat file

```
@echo off
set /a x=0

:loop1



timeout /t 600

set day="%date:~-10,2%"
set month="%date:~-7,2%"
set year="%date:~-4,4%"
set hour="%time:~-11,2%"
set minute="%time:~-8,2%"

set time="%hour%.%minute%"

set date="%day%.%month%.%year%"

echo d | XCOPY Z:\copydirectory "G:\pastdirectory" /e

echo Loop number -^>%x%

set /a x=%x%+1

if %x% NEQ 10000 goto loop1

pause
```

Thanks to anyone who answers.

Edit: changed

variable time to T
and variable date to D

That seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `"` in your `set` statements.  This will put the double-quotes into the actual result.  Assuming that your first values were parsed correctly, when you next construct `date`, the result will be:

```
""26"."05"."2014""
```

Then, next time `"%date:~-4,4%"` will give you `"14"""`.

Remove all the quotes from `set` statements and try again.  If you still have issues, you may need to look into delayed variable expansion.  Check out the `setlocal` and `endlocal` commands.